# Php, how to kill the self-request?

Tags: php, apache, process

Lets imagine a request is done, which lasts for a while, until its running, Php is echo-ing content. To flush the content, I use:

```
echo str_repeat(' ', 99999).str_repeat(' ', 99999); ob_implicit_flush(true);
```

so, while the request is being processed, we actually can see an output.
Now I would like to have a button like "stop it" so that from Php I could kill this process (Apache process I guess). How to?

Comment: You can press the `cancel` button in your browser

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fork the process and kill it via PCNTL (pcntl_fork and pcntl_signal) ?

Comment: @marfis: You can only fork in the CLI API.

Comment: @symcbean: Ah, makes sense, never tried... ;)

Comment: @hex2mgl the process itself still keeps running....

Answer (score 2):

> Now I would like to have a button like "stop it" so that from Php I could kill this process

It's not clear what you're asking here. Normally PHP runs in a single thread (of execution that is - not talking about light weight processes here). Further for any language running as CGI/FastCGI/mod_php there aer no input events - input from the HTTP channel is only read once at the beeginning of execution.

It is possible (depending on whether the thread of execution is regularly re-entering the PHP interpreter) to ask PHP to run a function at intervals (register_tick_function()) which could poll for some event communicated via another channel (e.g. a different HTP request setting a semaphore).

Sending an stream of undefined and potentially very large length to the browser is a really bad idea. The right solution (your example is somewhat contrived) may be to to [spawn a background process](http://symcbean.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/php-and-long-running-processes.html) on the webserver and poll the output via Ajax. You would still need to implement some sort of control channel though.

Sometimes the thread of execution goes out of PHP and stays there for a long time. In many cases if the user terminates a PHP script which has a long running database query, the PHP may stop running but the SQL will keep on running until completion. There are solutions - bu you didn't say if that was the problem.